# Boostrap can't align form-group input inside form-group

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is a picture of whats happening:

[image]

I dont understand whythe form-group is inside a div of class="col-md col-sm-7" why is the form-group streching  further than the div container it is in? how do it fix that?

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "col-md-3 col-sm-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="datefieldjq form-control" name="StartDate" value="@dateval">
                <i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Department, new { @class = "col-md-3 col-sm-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department, selList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show more code before and after the code in question i think this is not enough

Comment: Why you have the need to place a '<div class="form-group">' inside a '<div class="form-group">'?

Comment: @Franco the inner form-group allows for the glyphicon to be displayed inline with the input box. The outer form-group allows the control-label to align properly like all the others on the page

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing that you're trying to align are the input fields. If I'm not mistaken then simply adding the same `size=""` attributes to your `<input>` should make them the same length.